# postfix | sender_bcc_maps for specific emails (with attach)

Tags: email, postfix

How, if possible, copy all incoming mail with attachments to *mybackup@example.net*

If I use `sender_bcc_map = type:table` - all mails will be copied, without attachments too. I do not need that, I just need email with attachments.

My postfix version was 2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Postfix can detects whether  an email has attachment or not by parsing the header. And for that, postfix has feature called header_checks and its variation. [RFC 2183 section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2.2) defined that an attachment should be use `Content-Dispostion: attachment;` header. So, we can use `mime_header_checks` to detects an attachment then tell postfix to copy (BCC) it.

```
# main.cf
mime_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/attachment_check

# /etc/postfix/attachment_check
/^Content-Disposition: attachment;/  BCC mybackup@example.net
```

Further info: [Postfix BUILTIN_FILTER_README](http://www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html) and [Filter mail attachments](http://www.devops.zone/mailserver/filter-mail-attachments-postfix/)

---

> How, if possible, copy all **incoming mail** with attachments to *mybackup@example.net*

FYI, Postfix doesn't have concept incoming and outgoing email. All email passed through postfix was considered coming from other client and postfix **relay** it, to other mailserver, LMTP server, mailbox and others. So I'm afraid that this method will affect your emails, both incoming and outgoing (with some exception below).

If your outgoing email source was sendmail (`mail` command) or submitted via submission (587) or submitted through IP Address 127.0.0.1, you can selectively turn off the header_checks. Specify this configuration in `master.cf`

```
# By default turn on header_checks
smtp                inet  n     -     n     -     -   smtpd
# Disable header_checks on loopback IP address 
127.0.0.1:smtp      inet  n     -     n     -     -   smtpd
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
# Disable header_checks when email enter via sendmail/mail command
pickup              fifo  n     -     n    60     1   pickup
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
# Disable header_checks on submission port
submission          inet  n     -     n     -     -   smtpd
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
```

Source: [Turning Off Body & Header Checks for Internal Users](http://www.seaglass.com/postfix/turning-off-body-checks.html)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but warning: unknown command in mime_header_checks map: BCC?attach@domain.tld

Comment: why there is `?` in warning `mime_header_checks map: BCC?attach@domain.tld`?